# Getting "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.impl.DSL" error in Gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, jooq

I'm trying to run a Gradle project that uses dcm (https://github.com/vmware/declarative-cluster-management).

I called "./gradlew build", which is successful, then "java -jar build/libs/project.jar" to run the main class, for which I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jooq/impl/DSL
    at com.rebalancer.LoadBalance.setup(LoadBalance.java:92)
    at com.rebalancer.LoadBalance.<init>(LoadBalance.java:43)
    at com.rebalancer.RebalancerExperiment.main(RebalancerExperiment.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.impl.DSL
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 3 more
```

I tried to ensure that the dependencies were set up correctly. The following is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.rebalancer.RebalancerExperiment'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.vmware.dcm:dcm:0.15.0'
    implementation "org.jooq:jooq:3.13.1"
    implementation "org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.13.1"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}"
    implementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:${junitJupiterVersion}"
    implementation "org.junit-pioneer:junit-pioneer:${junitPioneerVersion}"
}
```

The DCM project also uses the jooq library, so I ensured that the two versions are using the same version (and I am avoiding a version conflict) by using "./gradlew dependencies". These are the dependencies for the runtime:

```
+--- com.vmware.dcm:dcm:0.15.0
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:{strictly [2.17.1, 3[; prefer 2.17.1} -> 2.17.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:{strictly [2.17.1, 3[; prefer 2.17.1} -> 2.17.1
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:{strictly [2.17.1, 3[; prefer 2.17.1} -> 2.17.1
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.33
|    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1
|    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1 (*)
|    +--- org.jooq:jooq:3.13.1
|    |    +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2
|    |    \--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1
|    |         \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
|    +--- org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.13.1
|    |    \--- org.jooq:jooq:3.13.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.11.1 -> 3.10.0
|    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.4 -> 2.5.1
|    |    \--- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.3
|    +--- org.apache.calcite:calcite-core:1.30.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.calcite:calcite-linq4j:1.30.0
|    |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.10.0
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.calcite.avatica:avatica-core:1.20.0
|    |    |         +--- org.apache.calcite.avatica:avatica-metrics:1.20.0
|    |    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.33
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.33
|    |    +--- com.esri.geometry:esri-geometry-api:2.2.0
|    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.5.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.calcite.avatica:avatica-core:1.20.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.10.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.33
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.10.0
|    |    +--- com.google.uzaygezen:uzaygezen-core:0.2
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1 -> 3.8
|    |    +--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.7.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.33
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13
|    |    +--- net.hydromatic:aggdesigner-algorithm:6.0
|    |    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 -> 1.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.6.0
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.6.1
|    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0
|    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.31
|    +--- com.facebook.presto:presto-parser:0.238.2
|    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    +--- io.airlift:slice:0.38
|    |    |    \--- org.openjdk.jol:jol-core:0.2
|    |    +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7.1
|    |    \--- com.facebook.airlift:log:0.191
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.11.1
|    +--- com.google.ortools:ortools-java:9.1.9490
|    |    +--- com.google.ortools:ortools-linux-x86-64:9.1.9490
|    |    +--- com.google.ortools:ortools-darwin-x86-64:9.1.9490
|    |    +--- com.google.ortools:ortools-win32-x86-64:9.1.9490
|    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.8.0
|    |    |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0
|    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.18.0
|    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.15.0 -> 3.18.0
+--- org.jooq:jooq:3.13.1 (*)
+--- org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.13.1 (*)
+--- com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre (*)
+--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
|    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.2 (c)
|    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.2 (c)
|    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2
|    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
|    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.2
|    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2
|    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2 (*)
|    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2
|         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|         +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|         +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.2
|         |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|         |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|         |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
|         |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.2 (*)
|         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2 (*)
\--- org.junit-pioneer:junit-pioneer:1.4.2
     +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.1 -> 5.7.2 (*)
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api -> 5.7.2 (*)
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params -> 5.7.2 (*)
     +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons -> 1.7.2 (*)
     \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher -> 1.7.2
          +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
          +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
          \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.2 (*)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I called (...) "java -jar build/libs/project.jar"

That is your problem. You have to give `java` not just your own code, but the classpath with all dependencies you used. Those aren't magically included. If you use Gradle to start the application, instead of manually calling `java`, it will do that for you automatically.